# Trouble Using BackupRead Function

Tags: c, winapi

I have been trying to use the function in order to read alternate data streams, however I have been able to read only the file name. I want to read the content of the Alternate Stream.
I have been using the code from the following [link](http://www.rootkitanalytics.com/userland/Exploring-Alternate-Data-Streams.php).

What should I do in order to read the contents of the alternate stream? 
I tried reading the documentation and looked for examples but havent really found anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code your question refers to uses BackupRead to enumerate the names of the alternate streams (if any).  It skips the actual content of each stream by calling BackupSeek to move directly to the next header.

You could either modify the code so that it reads the content rather than skipping it, or you can use the names to open and read from each stream separately.

To open a stream in file `a.txt` whose stream name is `xyzzy`, use the filename `a.txt:xyzzy`.